# Graph returned an error: (#200) Permissions error

Tags: php, facebook, publish

when I publish a post to my page, it's working fine, but when I post to page through set page ID instead of "me", 
the response as the following:
Graph returned an error: (#200) Permissions error
the source code as the following:

```
require_once 'src/Facebook/autoload.php';

//*
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['app_id'] = $config['appId'];
$config['secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['app_secret'] = $config['secret'];
define('APP_ID', $config['appId']);
define('APP_SECRET', $config['secret']);
//$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
$config['default_graph_version'] = 'v2.5'; 
$config['page_id']  =   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';  

$config['facebook']['permissions'] = array(
  'email',
  'user_location',
  'user_birthday',
  'publish_actions',
  'publish_pages',
  'manage_pages',
  'public_profile',
);

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook($config);




if(isset($_SESSION['fb_access_token'])) {
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['fb_access_token'];

} else {

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

        if(isset($accessToken)) {
            $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

            // longlived access token
            if (!$accessToken->isLongLived()) {
                $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken); 
            }
        }

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}



if(isset($accessToken)) {
    // Logged in!
    $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

    try {
        $response = $fb->get('/'.$config['page_id'].'/feed', $accessToken);

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        //exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        //exit;
    } 
} else {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $redirect_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirect_url, [ 'manage_pages', 'publish_pages', 'publish_actions' ]);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}





on other action in same page 


$page_access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';







// instance
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'     => APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

$linkData = [
  'link' => encodeurl(array('page'=>'page','lang'=>'ar','id'=>$_id,'beg'=>0,'unuse'=>$xtitlex)),
  'message' => $xtitlex,
  'source' => $publish,//$fb->fileToUpload($publish),
  'caption' => DOMAIN_,
  "picture" => $publish,
  "name" => $xtitlex,
  "description" => $xdescriptionx
 ];



try {
    //
    $response = $fb->post('/'.$config['page_id'].'/feed', $linkData, $page_access_token);

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    //print_r($linkData);
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: publish_actions, manage_pages, publish_pages: permissions has been activated for this application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the Access Token you used is generated as "Page Access Token" not "User Token". It is a bit tricky and took me a moment.

1. go to "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/"
2. drop down "User Token" menu
3. pick "Page Access Token"
4. blue button "Generate Access Token"
5. copy and use new token

Every time you add or remove Permissions, token changes!

Screenshot
[image: screenshot of permissions]

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you are not using a Page Token with the correct permissions. Make sure you are using a Page Token instead of a User Token and make sure it includes `publish_pages`. You can test your Token in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Make sure the Page ID shows up, and the `publish_pages` permission.

Answer (score 0):

My app types was business and I just added all the permissions from the given list and after I added all permissions, Facebook asked me to review permissions, I simply kept clicking on OK and everything worked, the error went